# How do I know if my Perl module is being called from inside of a test?

Tags: unit-testing, perl

Suppose I have a Perl module `My::Module` and I want it to output some useful information if I'm running inside of a unit test (i.e. something using `Test::Builder` or `Test2`, but not if I'm running outside of a unit test. How would I do that?

I realize this is a weird edge case, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: More of an opinion question but my approach would be to set an environment variable when testing and condition the behavior on that. You can even set a constant so that such statements are optimized out when the environment variable is not set, similar to for example the [MOJO_CLIENT_DEBUG setting for Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/source/Mojo::UserAgent#L15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for tests, say, to insert some temporary debugging code, I test for a function that would be defined in the test modules. For me, that is `&Test::More::diag`.

```
sub foo {
    ...
    defined(&Test::More::diag) && Test::More::diag("bar is $bar");
    ...
}
```

You can also inspect `%INC` to see if the test modules have been loaded

```
if ($INC{"Test/Builder.pm"}) { print STDERR "debugging info"; }
```

Comment: The only drawback to this approach is that if you want to disable the debug output when using the test distributions you have to go in and edit the modules directly.

Comment: How about checking for `$ENV{HARNESS_ACTIVE}`?

Comment: The other drawback is that Test::Builder being loaded is not a 100% guarantee that a test is currently being run (though it is a strong indicator). Environment variables are explicit in their meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I use environment variables assigned to constants to control these types of things in my modules (as stated in the OP comments). You can set the environment variables at the command line before running your programs/tests, or set the variables within the test files themselves in a `BEGIN` block.

Module:

```
package Module;

use warnings;
use strict;

use constant IN_TEST => $ENV{IN_TEST} || 0;

sub exec {
    warn "We're in testing mode!" if IN_TEST;
    return 25;
}

1;
```

Test file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
    $ENV{IN_TEST} = 1;
}

use lib 'lib';

use Module;
use Test::More;

is Module::exec(), 25, "exec() returns correct integer";

done_testing();
```

Normal script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib 'lib';

use Module;

Module::exec();
```

There is no output when running the script, as the function being called simply returns a value. However, when running the test file:

```
We're in testing mode! at lib/Module.pm line 9.
ok 1 - exec() returns correct integer
1..1
```

If you set the environment variable at the command line (or otherwise) before running a normal script that doesn't set it, you'll get the debug output all the same.